# Do Reapers detect the Normandy's presence when scanning faster as you approach closer towards the end of the game?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I seem to have noticed that the Reaper alertness/presence indicator has been more and more sensitive and less forgiving as I'm approaching closer towards the end of the game.

Is this something that I think it's happening or does the game increase the speed at which you are detected towards the end?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think so. It's more based on how close your scan was to the location of the reapers, I think you've just been scanning closer and not noticing.

Comment: @MrSmooth na, now with just a simple scan *right* next to the planet, the reaper alertness bar goes off the charts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the detection speed increases later in the game.
The game does increase the speed of detection at the end; it seems like the AI gets smarter and smarter, doesn't it? :) Well with ME3, there are very advanced examples of AI (compared to other games), and this is another example of where they did it to increase the difficulty/get ya' thinking. I personally don't like how it seems like they evolve, but it happens, so what can I say? 
Sources: I timed detection early vs. end of the game.

Hope this helps!